# is $y[n] = y[n - 4] + x[n - 4]$ time variant or invariant?

Tags: discrete-signals, linear-systems, infinite-impulse-response

I am confused about a solution because there is feedback.
Let's introduce a delay parameter $k$ and rewrite the system equation as:

$$ y \left[ n \right] = y \left[ n - 4 - k \right] + x \left[ n - 4 - k \right] $$

Now, we can see that the output $y \left[ n \right]$ depends on the input $x \left[ n - 4 - k \right]$ and the previous output $y \left[ n - 4 - k \right]$, which confirms that the system is still time-invariant.

Note that if the system were time-variant, the output would depend directly on the time index $n$, and introducing a delay $k$ would change the output for the same input signal. However, that is not the case here, and the system remains time-invariant.

Am I correct?

Comment: Welcome and congrats: Your reasoning, approach and results are indeed correct! Feedback (mostly) determines whether a system is FIR or IIR but has nothing to do with time invariance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try computing the z-transform of the original and the delayed version of the signal.
If you find them to be similar, then the system is time-invariant. Else, it is not.

In the following case, we have:
$$y_{1}[n] = x[n-4] + y_{1}[n-4]$$

The Z-transform is a linear operator, so we get the following:

$$ \mathcal{Z} \{ y_{1}[n] \} = \mathcal{Z} \{x[n-4] \} + \mathcal{Z} \{y_{1}[n-4] \}$$

$$Y_{1}(z) = X(z) \cdot z^{-4} + Y_{1}(z) \cdot z^{-4} $$
After manipulating the above formula, we get:
$$H_{1}(z) = \frac{Y_{1}(z)}{X(z)} = \frac{z^{-4}}{1-z^{-4}}$$

Now, let's consider the output $y_2{n}$ in the case of the delayed version of $x[n]$

$$y_2[n] = x[n-4-k] + y_2[n-4]$$
Calculating the Z-transform of both sides leads us to:

$$ \mathcal{Z} \{ y_{2}[n] \} = \mathcal{Z} \{x[n-k-4] \} + \mathcal{Z} \{y_{2}[n-4] \}$$

$$Y_{2}(z) = X(z) \cdot z^{-4} \cdot z^{-k}+ Y_{2}(z) \cdot z^{-4} $$
This time, the transfer function is:
$$H_{2}(z) = \frac{Y_{2}(z)}{X(z)} = \frac{z^{-4}}{1-z^{-4}} \cdot z^{-k}$$

$$H_{2}(z) = H_{1}(z) \cdot z^{-k}$$

So, the output with the delayed version of the input signal $x[n]$ is just the first output with a time delay factor $k$.

Which means that the filter is time-invariant.

Answer (score 0):

**1.-** Before `k` is introduced, or what's the same, while `k=0`, then the system coefficients `a` `b` are constant, therefore the system is apparently time invariant indeed.

```
b2*y(n)=b5*y(n-4)+a5*x(n-4)

b=[0 b2 0 0 b4]
a=[0 0  0 0 a4]
```

**2.**- Now `k~=0`

`~=` is MATLAB for **different than**

But what happens when `k` goes from `k=0` to for instance `k=1` ?

Now the system is

```
b2*y(n)=b5*y(n-4-1)+a5*x(n-4-1)
```

and the system coefficients have changed in time

```
b=[0 b2 0 0 0 b4]
a=[0 0  0 0 0 a4]
```

`b4` and `a4` have shifted 1 delay backward in time, as if pause button pressed for 1 delay.

When `k=0` then `b(5)=b4` and `b(6)=0`

but when `k=1` then `b(5)=0` and `b(6)=b5`

Changing `k` value once implies the system is at least once time variant.

A one-off time variant is time variant indeed.

So, one could reasonably argue that there's no need to be so strict, that introducing such parameter alone doesn't tell whether the system is or is not time invariant.

Furthermore, one could add that the **one-off** could be  ignored, for the sake of keeping further formulation simple, or the term **stationary** could be used; if `k` doesn't change fast enough, it all might make sense.

But since it has not been mentioned in the question that `k` is held constant, it is reasonable to assume that as an independent parameter it's going to change more than once.

Why introducing as parameter and **not** as **constant** if not to be able to change it?

For all the above said and without any further comment, without clearly stating that `k` is a constant, it would be safer to say that **the system is time variant** indeed.

**This system is as time variant as** `k` **may be.**

Answer (score 0):

Your conclusion that the system is time-invariant is correct, but I don't completely follow your argument. I would suggest the following procedure: let $y_2[n]$ be the system's response to a time-shifted input $x[n-k]$:

$$y_2[n]=y_2[n-4]+x[n-k-4]\tag{1}$$

Rewrite the original difference equation with $n$ replaced by $n-k$:

$$y[n-k]=y[n-k-4]+x[n-k-4]\tag{2}$$

Now we need to check if $(1)$ is compatible with $(2)$ with $y_2[n]$ replaced by $y[n-k]$, which is indeed the case and which leads us to the conclusion that the system is time-invariant.